# Sending page identifier with event to Google analytics via PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, event-tracking, measurement-protocol

Not sure if stackoverflow is the appropriate place to post this but couldn't find a better place.

I'm working on a directory style site that has thousands of listings which visitors can submit their details to through a number of methods...

1. A single form on each of the listing pages.
2. A quick contact button. This triggers a form submission from previously stored user data.
3. A bulk enquiry form. Users input their search terms and a form submission is create for each listing matching the search query.

We want a way of tracking the number of submissions per listing in Google Analytics.

I was thinking of sending an event from the server* when the submission process is successful.

*Using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

However, not knowing Google Analytics that well I am unsure what is recommended way to send the page identifier with an event. Form what I can tell, I can't attach an event to a specific page URL but we do have [4 parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events) (`category`, `action`, `label`, `value`) that we can utilise.

Would an event structure like the below be recommended?

- **Category:** `Conversion`
- **Action:** `Single submission` | `Quick contact` | `Bulk submission`
- **Label:** `id:192944` | `https://example.com/listing-uri/`

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Though it isn't clear to me why you would do this server side. To use the measurement protocol, you would also need to capture the user's GAid assigned to them via cookie on visit. You can simply attach an event to successful submission and have this taken care of by the GA library via events.

Your event structures are good. I wouldn't capture it as "id:1992944 | URL", I'd just use "1992944". This is because each event is already tied to the page via the "page path" dimension.